# Error: Calling dropdownlist in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this code below. I just want to call/use the dropdown list but it is inside a item template. As I run the code, I encountered an error. Please help me.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="statusDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="statusDDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void statusDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlStatus = new DropDownList();
    ddlStatus = auditGridView.FindControl("statusDDL") as DropDownList;

    if (ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text == "Closed")
    {
        //do logic here
    }
}
```

Im encountering an error: object reference not set to an instance of the object. WHY? I already declared the dropdown list as shown in the code above.

Comment: try using gridview rowediting event:
protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sender` in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler:

```
protected void statusDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if ((sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text == "Closed")
    {
        //do logic here
    }
}
```

However, this is rather Winform style programming. Using WPF you should really look into [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). But as you are using `asp:DropDownList` I'm not sure it's WPF?